# Given a URL how can I figure out the Geo where it is likely to originating from?

Tags: facebook, geolocation, saas

I am working on a certain problem where given a URL I need to map it to a country. Even if I can reliably answer the question "Is this particular URL relevant to United States?" that should be sufficient.

I am happy to have false negatives but never a false positive.

Currently I am considering the following approach.

- See if the domain name of the URL is in top 1000 .com domains on Alexa for USA.
- Check if the the link was shared by US users on Facebook or twitter.

Has anyone solved this kind of problem before ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/ but you need to get the IP address from your URLs domain before you can access the GeoIP database with this address.

There are a lot of interfaces to the GeoIP dataset for different languages: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/#MaxMind_APIs

Have a look at a sample NodeJS project here:

https://github.com/tobilg/GeoLocateURL

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out the [userinfo.io](http://userinfo.io) API or javascript library which is free and gets its data from a merge of several geolocation databases for more accuracy.

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/userinfo/1.0.0/userinfo.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
UserInfo.getInfo(function(data) {
  // the "data" object contains the info
}, function(err) {
  // the "err" object contains useful information in case of an error
});
</script>
```

The response will look like:

```
{
  request_date: "2014-09-18T04:11:25.154Z",
  ip_address: "192.77.237.95",
  position: {
    latitude: 37.7758,
    longitude: -122.4128,
    accuracy: 3   // This is the accuracy radius, in kilometers
  },
  continent: {
    name: "North America",
    code: "NA",
  },
  country: {
    name: "United States",
    code: "US",
  },
  city: {
    name: "San Francisco",
    code: "94103"
  }
}
```